# Most updated repositories for Linux?

Tags: rpm

I currently use the EPEL  and FamilleCollet Repos and I wonder whether there are others trustworthy RPM that update more frequently?

For e.g the latest EPEL release 6.8 install  `Nginx 1.0.15`
 which is a very old version

Comment: nginx maintain their own repo.

Comment: We can't tell you what "the most updated repositories" are - or more accurately we can, but tomorrow the answer will be wrong. You need to do your own research here, and keep your own *internal* answer up to date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the best and most maintained non-suported repos are the DAG, RPMforge (RepoForge), EPEL and REMI (FamilleCollet), I have DAG and RPMforge  as well as EPEL enabled on my Centos 6 box but the latest version of nginx is the one you mentioned from EPEL.

As a rule, later versions of software have not been added to a repo for many reasons, it could be due to a conflict, or  stability concern, if you *need* the new features being offered by the latest versions of software your best bet would normally be compiling it from source. But this could be time consuming if the dependancies are extensive and/or the dependancies require you to compile them from source also.

You could also consider contacting the package maintainers (normally via IRC) to see if there is a reason they have not updated to later versions of the software you are after, although I doubt you would get a timely response.

But depending on how easy you want your system to maintain, how stable you need it to be, and how much you need the latest features of the software, you need to balance up whether to compile from source or stick to the package in the repos.